# how to integrate TopShelf with asp.net web API .net core 3.1 application

Tags: asp.net-core, topshelf

I like lots of TopShelf features like `RunAsVirtualServiceAccount`, `StartAutomaticallyDelayed`, etc. and would like to integrate with asp.net core 3.1 web api application which I will host as window service.

Could someone suggest how to integrate Topshelf with asp.net Core web API application.

I heard `Worker Service`, but I don't want to run things as background service. I want to host web api application as windows service. Thanks!

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseHttpSys();
                webBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    services.Configure<HttpSysOptions>(options =>
                    {
                        options.UrlPrefixes.Add(context.Configuration["HttpSysOptions:UrlPrefix"]);
                    });
                });

                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            //host as window service
            .UseWindowsService()
```